# flutter print a single value from json api

Tags: flutter

i am new to flutter and want to print only my name
my code is below i tryed but i am getting error

```
var resBody = await http.post(
        my_url,
        headers: header,
      );

      print(resBody.body);
```

i get data like this

`[{name:hari,age:26,sex:male}]`

i want to print name only i tryed  like this but it does not work i dont know whats wrong here

`print(resBody.body.name);`

i getiing error
how do i print any data like that

Comment: Try `jsonDecode(resBody.body)['name']`

Comment: The data returned is an array, are you expecting it as an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the data using key of the json object try this

```
 var resBody = await http.post(
                my_url,
                headers: header,
              );
        
             final data=jsonDecode(resBody.body)//Parses the string and returns the resulting Json object
        
        print(data[0]["name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,and used `jsonDecode(resBody.body)['name']` [**`jsonDecode`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html)

```
var resBody = await http.post(
        my_url,
        headers: header,
      );
final jsonData=jsonDecode(resBody.body)['name'];//it prints only name of your json string

      print(jsonData);
```